# Can a C# DataGridView cell be both Multiline and single line?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm building a DataGridView dynamically, and the textboxes potentially have an AutoComplete custom source associated with them. Under some circumstances, when I set textbox.Multiline to true, I get the following effect. If I'm not actively editing the cell, it looks like this:

[image: This is the selected, but unedited cell]

However, if I try to edit the cell, it looks like this:

[image: This is the cell in edit mode]

If I move the cursor around this edit mode cell, focus hops out of the cell entirely, instead of moving the text or expanding the cell height. It looks as if it's trying to be in multiline and single line mode at the same time, but I'm not sure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: look up how to use datagridview ItemTemplates you would do this using a multi-line textbox for example

Comment: Update: it appears that the problem is that the Location of the textbox in the DataGridView is set to (3,49) instead of (0,0). Trying to force it to `new Point(0,0)` doesn't buy me anything, though. Have I run into a Microsoft bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - not a root cause. In EditingControlShowing, I do the following:

```
textBox.Dock = textBox.Multiline ? DockStyle.Fill : DockStyle.None;
```

where I've set `textBox = (TextBox) e.Control;`

It's a sledgehammer solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Lets give a name to the DataGridView object: dgv,
So On dgv_CellEnter event add following lines

```
int idxcol = dgv.Columns["YourColumnName"].Index;
            if (e.ColumnIndex == idxcol)
                dgv.Columns[idxcol].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
```

and on dgv_CellLeave event add the following lines

```
int idxcol = dgv.Columns["YourColumnName"].Index;
if (e.ColumnIndex == idxcol )
            {
                dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            }
```